# YA novel about dystopian future with non-human overlords and teenage heroes

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dystopia

I read a YA novel in the early 2000s that I think takes place on Earth some time in the future. The human race has been enslaved by some other race, possibly aliens. If I remember correctly, humans were kept as slaves for some purpose and then exterminated at age 16, and I think some girls were kept to breed.

I remember scenes of a band of teenagers walking around sewers fighting these aliens who bled a blue "ichor." The only thing I distinctly remember about the book was that it was the first place I saw the word "ichor."

This is a pretty sorry description; but does anyone have a clue what this book was?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your description sounds very similar to the novel *[**Shade's Children**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shade%27s_Children)*, by Garth Nix.

> Shade's Children takes place in a not-so-distant future where evil Overlords have ruled for fifteen years due to a catastrophic "Change" which caused all people over the age of fourteen to simply disappear. Since then, the children have been rounded up and placed in prison-like dorms. No child may live past their fourteenth birthday [...]. There is only one exception to this rule: some young women are kept for "breeding" to maintain the supply of children, until a suggested maximum age of eighteen.

Comment: Yes that's the one! I skimmed the plot summary and don't remember much of it; I must not have finished it. Very dark stuff for a YA book, and even for Garth Nix